# How to solve the out of memory error when setting image from drawable?

Tags: android

I am working on android project. My apk size is 50mb because my project contains lot of images and I kept all my images in drawable folder. But now the problem is sometimes when i click on the button to display the image it is displaying error message saying that outofmemory error. Please anybody suggest me how to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

[Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) provide a solution.
The idea is that you should scale down the images before loading them in memory.

Answer (score 0):

i am not Sure but about your exact Problem but Here is the link in which you can get your solution

[Out of Memory Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object/823966#823966)